# How should I deal with sub attributes of xml data when loading onto mysql?

Tags: mysql, xml

I have some xml files (example below). As you can see in the xml, `id` 4 has 3 entries for `tax`. When I load it right now, only the last entry gets inserted into the table.

1. How can I include all 3 of them when I load it into mysql?
2. What's the best approach to deal with sub attributes of data in xmls?

Table:

```
mysql> create table if not exists trial (
    -> id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY,
    -> tax TEXT,
    -> shipping VARCHAR(4),
    -> cost NUMERIC
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> LOAD XML INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/trial.xml' INTO TABLE trial ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<entry>';
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from trial;
+----+------+----------+------+
| id | tax  | shipping | cost |
+----+------+----------+------+
|  1 | NULL | YES      |   10 |
|  2 | NULL | NO       |   20 |
|  3 | NULL | YES      |   30 |
|  4 | NULL | YES      |   90 |
+----+------+----------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<feed>
    <entry>
        <id>1</id>
        <tax>
            <shipping>YES</shipping>
            <cost>10.0</cost>
        </tax>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>2</id>
        <tax>
            <shipping>NO</shipping>
            <cost>20.0</cost>
        </tax>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>3</id>
        <tax>
            <shipping>YES</shipping>
            <cost>30.0</cost>
        </tax>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>4</id>
        <tax>
            <shipping>YES</shipping>
            <cost>70.0</cost>
        </tax>
        <tax>
            <shipping>YES</shipping>
            <cost>80.0</cost>
        </tax>
        <tax>
            <shipping>YES</shipping>
            <cost>90.0</cost>
        </tax>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: If this question is more suitable in stackoverflow than here, please let me know.

Comment: You try to treate your XML as multi-level one whereas MySQL can process XML as single-level only.

Comment: @Akina right, is there a way around this? I'm not in control of creating the xml so can't do much there. One way I can think of is to process the file, add attributes or something like that, and rewrite the file before consuming into sql. Other way is maybe to associate it with another table? Not sure thinking out loud here. Please let me know.

Comment: If you can to process your XML then convert it to something like `<entry>
<tax>
<id>1</id>
<shipping>YES</shipping>
<cost>10.0</cost>
</tax>
</entry>
...
<entry>
<tax>
<id>4</id>
<shipping>YES</shipping>
<cost>70.0</cost>
</tax>
</entry>
<entry>
<tax>
<id>4</id>
<shipping>YES</shipping>
<cost>80.0</cost>
</tax>
</entry>
...` - i.e. move `id` attribute into each `tax`.

Comment: Alternatively - load the whole XML and parse it in iterative stored procedure.

Comment: I can't put the `id` into `tax` since id is the primary key and I'd be violating the constraint there. The stored procedure sounds like an alternative I could use. Can you please post any useful links I could follow?

Comment: *I can't put the id into tax since id is the primary key and I'd be violating the constraint there.* o_O If so the how you are going to "include all 3 of them when I load it into mysql"? How does the final table state should look like? provide not retrieved but desired data state.

Comment: Oh, I was actually hoping I could have them as an array of values. That's how I started off and hit this challenge. I honestly don't know how the table should end up looking, I should be taking the decision on this. I thought since each record has a unique id, then each record must/should be unique.

Comment: *I was actually hoping I could have them as an array of values.* This is not a problem. Use JSON column and store an array of objects.

Comment: I was able to solve this temporarily by creating another table `taxes` with a PK `pk_id`, `id`, `shipping`, `cost`  and loading the xml again, and changing `rows identified by <entry>` to `rows identified by <tax>`. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go forward, but seems to work for me. This way I can reference that table to get the relevant details for a particular `id`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Test does it works correctly when the entities are not ordered in the file (for example, swap entries with id=2 and 3 in your sample XML).